# How can I make my component library use the app's material theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to figure out a way to make my standalone/reusable component library use the app's material theme in Angular. More specifically, I'm trying to access the theme colors in the component, so that I can set a border color based on if the theme is light or dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component, you can add a reference to the theme stylesheet :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/your/template.html',
  styleUrls: ['/path/to/the/theme/stylesheet', '...']
})
```

Or if you use scss, just import the theme stylesheet in your component's stylesheet, this will allow you to use the theme colors.

```
@import 'path/to/the/theme/stylesheet.scss'
```

Comment: Will this work the same if, for example, the component library is in my `node_modules` directory? I'm trying to make it so I can `npm install` these components and still use the app's material theme. The app's theme file would always be in the same spot.

Comment: Yes, you just need to give the path to your stylesheet, relative to your `src/` folder